# Stub property and save other behaviour

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

Is it possible to stub only one property and keep other's behaviour using Rhino Mocks?

Upd.
Example:
I have a class with two properties

```
public class ClassA
{
 public string Property1
 {
  get
  {
   return "Property1";
  }
 }

 public string Property2
 {
  get
  {
   return "Property2";
  }
 }
}
```

I would like to get an instance of this object with the stubbed only Property1 (and property2 should work as it does).

When I use the following code:

```
ClassA classA = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ClassA>();
classA.Stub(c => c.Property1).Return("stubbed property 1");
```

and then try to access classA.Property2 it returns null.

Comment: What other behavior? Are you stubbing an interface? Give some example of what you have and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Partial Mock](http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/08/partial-mocks-explained/)